# Save large number of records using cakephp 2.0 takes long time

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

**In Cakephp 2.6**

I am using `$this->Model->saveAll(array_of_30000_rows);` its working fine, but it take so much time. 
As I see the `Model->saveAll()` calls `Model->save()` to save records one by one, Why?
Or is another way to save large number of records quickly?

Comment: Try to wrap it in transaction

Comment: Are you suggest to wrap in single statement ?

Comment: Use `$dataSource = $this->Mode->getDataSource();$dataSource->begin();$this->Model->saveAll(array_of_30000_rows);$dataSource->commit();`. Or create your own loop with single `$this->Model->save(row)` and e.g. commit  every 1000 rows. It should be significantly faster

Comment: Thanks for your advice but is much useful.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have set php's time limit set_time_limit(160); big enough.

```
foreach($savedata as $ssave){

$this->create();
$this->save($ssave, array('validate' => false));

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would check out [Update All](https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html#model-updateall-array-fields-mixed-conditions) if it's appropriate for your situation.  It has been faster than `saveAll` in my experience.